# React-Native- Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

Using gradle 4.3 to build a react-native app on windows 7 and I get the below error, Not sure what the issue is, any help will be apreciated.

```
C:\Users\username\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\username\AwesomeProject\node_modules (62ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 22):

Upgrade your build.gradle project file; com.android.tools.build:gradle version from 2.2.3 to use as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

You may or may not, also encounter this issue, please update your build tools.

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
```

Solution: update inside your project `/app/build.gradle` as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

Comment: Where to add the code `android { `? in the blocks of buildscript or all projects? or as a standalone block?

Comment: @TerrySmith The `android` block should already be there - that piece is in the `app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks heaps ! Worked for me too, but could anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: For me `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'` and in app/build.gradle `android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` worked fine